# How to read a multiple column from a .dat file in matplotlib and then plot then into multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-columns, subplot

I am trying to plot a five colum dat file into two subplots using matplotlib.
First colum from the dat file  will be same for both the subplots.
I could read the dat file in matplotlib but it is plotting only first three colums only (only one plot).

My file is sigma.dat with below entries

```
   0.013610  0.719520E-01  0.774371E-01  0.126304E-02  0.133856E-02
   0.040820  0.218942E+00  0.235756E+00  0.384315E-02  0.407507E-02
   0.068030  0.370247E+00  0.398893E+00  0.649864E-02  0.689443E-02
   0.095240  0.526034E+00  0.567041E+00  0.923211E-02  0.979962E-02
   0.122450  0.686473E+00  0.740396E+00  0.120463E-01  0.127937E-01
   0.149660  0.851747E+00  0.919171E+00  0.149441E-01  0.158801E-01
   0.176870  0.102205E+01  0.110358E+01  0.179285E-01  0.190620E-01
   0.204090  0.119764E+01  0.129394E+01  0.210038E-01  0.223444E-01
   0.231300  0.137860E+01  0.149035E+01  0.241710E-01  0.257286E-01
   0.258510  0.156522E+01  0.169312E+01  0.274349E-01  0.292199E-01
   0.285720  0.175773E+01  0.190255E+01  0.307990E-01  0.328224E-01
   0.312930  0.195639E+01  0.211891E+01  0.342672E-01  0.365405E-01
   0.340140  0.216143E+01  0.234251E+01  0.378436E-01  0.403789E-01
   0.367350  0.237315E+01  0.257367E+01  0.415324E-01  0.443426E-01
   0.394570  0.259192E+01  0.281281E+01  0.453396E-01  0.484383E-01
   0.421780  0.281787E+01  0.306012E+01  0.492672E-01  0.526684E-01
```

I tried to plot it with a small script but I am getting only single plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
with open("sigma.dat", "r") as f:
    x = []
    y1 = []
    y2 = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        row = line.split()
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y1.append(float(row[1]))
        y2.append(float(row[2]))

    pl.plot(x, y1, x, y2)
    pl.savefig("sigma.p`enter code here`ng", dpi=300)
```

I want to know how to plot this five colum dat file into two subplots, like clm:0:1:2; and clm:0:3:4. 
I expect the output image file should be having two subplots (2 1) with a space between both of them in one and no space between two subplots in another image.

Comment: PLease note that the common import abbreviation for `matplotlib.pyplot` is `plt`.

Comment: Would you consider using pandas for this? If you don't mind the overhead, it will make the code to read your file trivial.

Comment: Thanks dear Dan for your kind response. I am following the answer from SpghttCd in pondas. have a look at the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `matplotlib` [`subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) is the first address for generating multiple plots into one figure.
(See link for description and examples.)

So you could do

```
fig, axs = pl.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(x, y1)
axs[1].plot(x, y2)
```

instead of your plot command above.

---

However, please note that while reading a file like this is possible and correct, there are several tools which help you here so you do not have to program this very common task manually again and again.

The most important tools are imo `numpy` and `pandas`, perhaps you heard already about them and like to try yourself.

With `numpy` you could do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("sigma.dat")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, i+1])
```

With `pandas` you could do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sigma.dat", delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

---

Short Explanation:

With `numpy`, you import an *additional* library along with matplotlib, which helps you not only with reading data from files, but which is in fact *the* basic needed library to do scientific math and calculations in python.

`pandas` on the other hand *can replace* `matplotlib` and/or `numpy`, as it is built on top of both. It is a complete data analysis tool with a wide range of functions included for a variaty of standard approaches in this topic.

---

***Edit***:

After reading your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57869880/8300135), I think I understand a little more of your task, so this is an approach in Python to create four subplots with no space in between:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sigma.dat', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, header=None)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey='row', gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

axs[0, 0].plot(df[df.columns[:2]])
axs[0, 1].plot(df[df.columns[:2]]*1.2)
axs[1, 0].plot(df[df.columns[2:]])
axs[1, 1].plot(df[df.columns[2:]]*.75)
```

[image]

---

***EDIT2:***

Further attempt to copy [this handmade original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAjW7.jpg)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

axs[0, 0].plot(df[df.columns[:2]])
axs[0, 1].plot(df[df.columns[:2]]*1.2)
axs[1, 0].plot(df[df.columns[2:]])
axs[1, 1].plot(df[df.columns[2:]]*.75)
for i in range(2):
    axs[i, 1].spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 1))
    axs[i, 1].yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
    axs[i, 1].yaxis.set_label_position('right')

axs[0, 0].set_ylabel('A11')
axs[0, 1].set_ylabel('A12')
axs[1, 0].set_ylabel('A21')
axs[1, 1].set_ylabel('A22')

for ax, lbl in zip(axs.flatten(), list('abcd')):
    ax.text(.05, .9, f'({lbl})', transform=ax.transAxes)
axs[1, 0].set_xlabel('X-12-Scale', x=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear SpghttCd, your code" import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("sigma.dat")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, i+1])" worked for me but not as per what I am looking for. I want to plot the column 0,1, 2 in one subplot while colum 0,4,5 in other subplot. with axis lables, title at center top and center bottom and figure numbers like (a), (b).

Comment: Sorry - I read as stated above your next question, but didn't see your comment - only on mobile the last hours... However, perhaps the new pandas code eirks for you too, it includes plotting of the first 2 columns in s different axis than the last 2. But of course I can check sth similar for the numpy based script.

Comment: Yes, this pondas is working now for me. Could you please modify it so that I can get the plot as asked by me   https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAjW7.jpg . If possible please take care of tick fonts and tick labels as asked in the above link.  It would be a great help.