# How to manage tick lable and axis-lable in gnu multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

[image]I have two files each is having five columns where 1st will be the x-axis in both the data.
I want to make a multiplot 2 2 in GNU with zero spacing.
I could manage many things but I am could not fix below problems:
1. How to place the figure at the center of the page i.e. equal left right margin?  I set the left, right, top and bottom margin but it is not working.
2. How to number the figure. For example,  Figure 1 1 should be numbered as (a), figure 1 2 should be numbered as (b) and so on.
3. How to put tick lable and tick mark on the plot 1 2  and 2 2 on right side of the plot?
4. how to create a common title at the bottom of the figure representing the X-axis.

I  have tried to make gnu multiplot layout but still it is not giving desired results. The script I used is mentioned below:

My code is

```
[![set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 20cm,15cm  color solid lw 3 "Times-Roman" 24
reset
set lmargin screen 0.10
set rmargin screen 0.95
set bmargin screen 0.15
set tmargin screen 0.9

set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set tics font "Times-bold, 50"
set output "absorption.pdf"

set multiplot layout 2,2 margin 0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9 spacing 0.00, 0.00
set tics scale 1.2
set tics font "Times-bold, 26" 


set key spacing 1.2
unset key
set xrange \[0:8.5\] 
set yrange \[0:1\]
set xlabel ' '
set format x ""
set ylabel  'A11' font 'Times-bold, 26' offset 1,1,3
unset label
plot "data1.dat" u 1:($2/10**4) w l lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "red" title "x-D", 'data1.dat' u 1:($3/10**4)  w l lw 3 lc rgb "blue" title "z-D"

unset label
unset format x
unset key
set key inside center top                    # to adjust the legends position
set xrange \[0:8.5\]
set yrange \[0:1\]
set title ' '
set xlabel ' '
set xlabel ' '
set format x ""
set ylabel ' '
set format y " "
set key spacing 1.2
set ylabel 'A12' font 'Times-bold, 26' offset 1,0,3
plot "data1.dat" u 1:($4/10**2) w l lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "red" title "x-D", 'data1.dat' u 1:($5/10**2) w l lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "blue" title "Z-D"


unset label
unset format y
unset format x

unset key

set xrange \[0:8.5\]
set yrange \[0:1.08\]
set xlabel ' '
unset label
set ylabel 'A21'   font 'Times-bold, 28'
unset label
plot "data2.dat" u 1:($2/10) w l  lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "red" title "x-dir", 'data2.dat' u 1:($4/10) w l  lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "blue" title "z-dir" ,\

unset label
unset format x
unset key

set xrange \[0:8.5\]
set yrange \[0:1.08\]
set title ' '
set format y ""
set xlabel 'X-12-scale' font 'Times-bold, 28'
set ylabel 'A22' font 'Times-bold, 28'
plot "data2.dat" u 1:($3/10) w l lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "red" title "x-dir", 'data2.dat' u 1:($5/10) w l lw 3 lt 2 lc rgb "blue" title "z-dir"

unset label
unset format y
unset key

unset multiplot
set output][1]][1]
```

My data should be like what I want according to attached figure queries  and hand marks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dear sayan, This code is working and  I am not looking for debugging. Instead I am not able to edit it further for the asked queries.

Comment: Hey, please upload the figure you're talking about too.

Comment: Hii Sayan, Thanks for letting me. Now I have uploaded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set terminal pngcairo size 750,500 font ",10"
set output "Multiplot_2x2.png"
set multiplot \
    layout 2,2 rowsfirst \
    title "{/:Bold=11 Multiplot 2×2}" \
    margins screen 0.10,0.92,0.12,0.90 \
    spacing screen 0.00,0.00

set link y2
# Gaussian fuction
f(x,a,b,c) = a*exp(-((x-b)/c)**2)
# Parameters to first one
a1 = 0.95
b1 = 4.00
c1 = 1.00
# Parameters to second one
a2 = 0.95
b2 = 5.00
c2 = 1.00
# Line style
set style line 1 lc "#e41a1c"   # red
set style line 2 lc "#377eb8"   # blue
# -----------------------------------------------
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:1.0]
set xtics format ""
set ytics
set ylabel "y-label"
set label 1 "{/:Bold (a)}" at graph 0.05, 0.9
plot f(x,a1,b1,c1) w l ls 1 notitle, f(x,a2,b2,c2) w l ls 2 notitle
# -----------------------------------------------
unset ylabel
set ytics format ""
set y2tics format ""
set y2label "y2-label"
set label 1 "{/:Bold (b)}"
plot f(x,a1,b1,c1) w l ls 1 title "Your title 1", f(x,a2,b2,c2) w l ls 2 title "Your title 2"
# -----------------------------------------------
unset y2tics
unset y2label
set xtics 0,2,9 format "%g"
set ytics 0,0.2,0.9 format "%g"
set ylabel "y-label"
set label 1 "{/:Bold (c)}"
plot f(x,a1,b1,c1) w l ls 1 notitle, f(x,a2,b2,c2) w l ls 2 notitle
# -----------------------------------------------
unset ylabel
set xtics 0,2,10
set xlabel "common x-label" offset screen -0.20,0.0
set ytics format ""
set y2tics
set y2label "y2-label"
set label 1 "{/:Bold (d)}"
plot f(x,a1,b1,c1) w l ls 1 notitle, f(x,a2,b2,c2) w l ls 2 notitle
# -----------------------------------------------
```

Result

[image: result]

Comment: Dear GRSousaJr, This sound amazing for me. What is mean by set link y2
f(x,a,b,c) = a*exp(-((x-b)/c)**2)
a = 0.95
b = 5.00
c = 2.00

Comment: Also, legends are missing in your code. I need x-D as x||D and z-D as z 'perpendicular symbol' D (see im my image at right top plot) . Could you please help me for this?

Comment: It is a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), just a function to plot. `a`, `b`, and `c` are parameters. `set link y2` forces the `y2` axis to have identically the same range, scale, and direction as the `y` axis.

Comment: Ok, could you please have look at my another query?

Comment: Thanks Dear GRSousaJr for your kind support. I have last few concerns.  I am not able to move the -lable of the plot (c) a litl bit outside. I need x-D as x||D and z-D as z 'perpendicular symbol' D (see im my image at right top plot). and all the fonts in Times New Roman Bold.

Comment: The **(a)**, **(b)**, **(c)** and **(d)** labels are defined by `set label 1 "{/:Bold (a)}" at graph 0.05, 0.9`, i.e., by `graph coordinates`. Type `help coordinates` to more information. The perpendicular symbol (⟂) using _Times New Roman_ font can be inserted using `{/Symbol \\^}`.

Comment: It helped me a lot. May be I could not explained what I wanted in my previous comment.  I want to move y-lable of bottom left plot a little outside. I used set "y-label"  offset -2.2,0 but I am not able to move it a little outside. I tried with offset x, 0.0. where I varied x from - to +. It can move to inside the plot but not going away from the plot.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks Dear GRSousaJr.